# "Не отпускаются" клавиши

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private bool nonKeysEntered = false;

public void MyKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    nonKeysEntered = false;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
        KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.ControlKey);
        KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.S);
        nonKeysEntered = true;
    }
}

public void MyKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (nonKeysEntered) e.Handled = true;
}

static class KeyboardSend
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
    private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

    public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    }

    public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
}
```

Открываю блокнот, нажимаю клавишу `пробел`, срабатывает комбинация `ctrl+s` и после этого, такое ощущение, будто эти клавиши нажаты остаются навсегда (скролю в браузере - происходит увеличение/уменьшение страницы и т.д)

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, в чем ошибка? В данный момент остановился на коде выше.

Comment: Можно бы и KeyUp послать...

Comment: А что за `KeyboardSend`? Вы сами его написали или это класс из какой-либо библиотеки?

Comment: @Эникейщик, KeyUP вообще отказывается нажимать клавишу, почему-то...

Comment: @defaultlocale, добавил этот класс в пост

Comment: @Максим Пробовали сначала нажать клавиши (`KeyDown`), а затем отпустить их (`KeyUp`)? Как показано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407584/sendkeys-send-and-windows-key

Comment: @defaultlocale, пробовал многое, но так не пробовал. Работает! Спасибо! Только предварительно пришлось убрать хэндл из MyKeyPress